# events.js:72 meteor up deploy

Tags: meteor

i tried everything what i found in net but nothing helped me... i try deploy app in my server on Debian 8.2, and every time after: mup deploy i got this:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

Building Started: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myName/Google Drive/_projects/Coda/lottato_com

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
```

my mup.json look lik:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "server IP",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "blablabla"
    }
  ],   
  "setupMongo": false,
  "setupNode": true,
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  "appName": "myAppName",
  "app": "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myName/Google Drive/_projects/Coda/myAppName",
  "env": {
    "MONGO_URL": "//<login>:<password>@ds061464.mongolab.com:61111/myAppdb",
    "ROOT_URL": "http://myApp.com"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

i can't handle with this issue almost 3 day! i tried deploy form server, change path, but it still didn't work and don't yet work...

and when i try to look in log, i got this:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

[178.63.41.196] tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/upstart/lottato.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

also u tried use mupx insted of mup, n now i got:

```
Invalid configuration file mup.json: There is no meteor app in the current app path.
```

new mup.json look like:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "server IP",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "blablabla",
      "env": {}
    }
  ],
  "setupMongo": false,
  "appName": "appName",
  "app": "~/Google Drive/_projects/Coda/appName",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://appName.com",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://login:pass@ds035735.mongolab.com:35735/appName"
  },
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
}
```

but i tried any type of path, with ~ or full path, n always the same, installation is starting only when in field path i writ:

```
"app": ".",
```

Comment: not sure it's related but try changing nodeVersion to 0.10.40.  0.10.36 does not seem to work..

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve this problem only with mupx + i moved project on server and deploy it from server to the same server.

Answer (score 0):

after increasing to 0.10.40 you should run 'mup setup' again followed by 'mup deploy'.

In my project I have mup.json in the project root (same level as .meteor) and
 `"app": "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/myName/Google Drive/_projects/Coda/myAppName"`

looks like

`"app": ".",`

Not sure if that is important.

Comment: i did. 
how can  mup.json be in the same folder if  mup.json on server (in new folder for deploy) and ur app is on ur local machine (laptop or pc) ?